# Conda silent install - system can not find specified path

Tags: conda, silent-installer, miniconda

I am trying to create an install script(batch file) for miniconda.  currently, my line for installing Conda itself reads:

`Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64/S/D=C:\Python`

I have tried adding a `"md\Python` while the drive is C - it makes no difference.  Whether there is a `Python` directory or not I get `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one here. Worked fine.

```
Miniconda3-4.5.4-Windows-x86_64.exe /S /InstallationType=AllUsers /D=c:\test
```

See [Silent Install : Anaconda Miniconda3 4.5.4](https://www.silent-install.net/software/anaconda/miniconda3/4.5.4) for other install options.